# google cloud platform blob.download_to_file where the file is downloaded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, blob, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

```
gcloud beta functions deploy gcp-data-transfer --project probable-scout-216702 --runtime python37 --trigger-bucket connector-test-data-securonix --entry-point detect_file
```

Above is the google cloud function I am using. it is a trigger on my google cloud storage bucket. My gcloud function is running but I don't know where the files are supposed to be downloaded.I was able to store it in a `/tmp/` directory but it's still not on my own system and I have no idea which `/tmp` it is downloading in. I am using following code :

```
def detect_file(file, context):
    destination_file_name = "/Securonix/file1.txt"
    f = open("/Securonix/file1.txt",'wb')
    bucket = validate_message(file, 'bucket')
    name = validate_message(file, 'name')
    print("here")
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket)
    blob = bucket.blob(name)
    blob.download_to_file(f)
    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
        name,
        destination_file_name))


def validate_message(message, param):
    var = message.get(param)
    if not var:
        raise ValueError('{} is not provided. Make sure you have \
                          property {} in the request'.format(param, param))
    return var
```

I am getting error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Securonix/file1.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `/tmp/` then your file name, this is because you can't create files on cloud function except `/tmp/` folder.

Your string is like:

```
/tmp/Securonix/file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Functions execution environment is [totally read-only except for `/tmp/`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system), so you must download to that directory.

A second issue (and the reason why you saw `FileNotFoundError` instead of `PermissionError`) is that the `/Securonix/` directory does not exist on the cloud function runtime. `open()` does not create new directories for you, you must create the directory before you can create a file in it.

Also: don't forget to [delete the file when you are done](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#always_delete_temporary_files) as it's stored in memory.

Comment: I don't know how to create directory in this Cloud Functions execution environment and similarly don't know how to access the /tmp/ folder in it.

Comment: You can create a directory with the [`os.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.mkdir) function. You can access files there with `open("/tmp/yourfile", "r")`. If you are trying to download a file in cloud functions and then access it from elsewhere, you are probably using the wrong tool for the job - you should download the file directly to the place where you want to use it.

Comment: Thanks david I want a data pipeline such that any change in google cloud storage bucket (objects in it) can be stored on my system. I am thinking pub-sub can do it for me. But I am not sure if pub sub would allow the publisher on GC storage to talk to subscriber on my ssh machines.

Comment: You can run a pull subscriber from any machine with internet access.

Comment: Cloud functions does not provide any persistent storage. You could use cloud functions to copy the object to a "backup bucket" on each change. Or, if you want the files on a local machine, you could run a pubsub pull subscriber on your local machine and save the files locally.

Comment: Yes, the pub sub pull or push subscriber is what I am thinking. Will post the solution design once tested.

Comment: Is there any way I can transfer file(objects) as it is from publisher to subscriber?

Comment: The [copy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#copy) API is probably what you need.

Comment: Thanks, David. I was able to accomplish this via Google Cloud pubsub without using copy(as I need all new files in my bucket written to my cluster I used trigger-bucket). The current issue I am solving is that my code is only able to write small files but not large ones.

Comment: I am not able to send big files via Google cloud pubsub, it seems like they are timing out. Where can I change configurations so that my files are transferred without any failures.

Comment: I recommend against putting whole files in pubsub. Better to have the source upload the file directly to GCS and then just have metadata including the URL to GCS in pubsub.

Comment: I am working for a client which uploads logs as large files to Google Cloud Storage. As I needed files as they get uploaded, I have used --trigger-bucket to publish these files and I have put subscribers on my end nodes. This whole process is working great for sending small files but not for large files. Please help.

Comment: So I realized that the max message size on PubSub is 10mb. So I am sending chunks of events now and not the entire file. it's working great for 20mb files but for 400mb files it's resulting in a google cloud functions execution stopped : timeout. I inxreased the timeout to the max of 9 mins for my google cloud function but still getting a timeout..